# Very small foundation pour

Tags: foundation

Going to have to pour a very small 3'x2' foundation.  I know that I should go easy on the water to prevent spalling problems, etc., but I'm looking for something better than chicken wire for reinforcement.  I'm afraid of rust problems, which can crack concrete because rust takes up more volume than the original iron/steel.

Obviously I don't need anything too substantial for such a small foundation, but I'd like something that isn't galvanized and is intended for encasement in concrete.  Anyone know of anything that would be suitable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use chicken wire or fiber glass meshing, they don't do anything.

When it comes to non rebar reinforcement you have some options. In your case I would add fibers. This type of reinforcement is called FRC or Fiber Reinforced Concrete.

[image]

Steel fibers add tensile strength and have no weak points like rebar does because they are spread throughout the slab. They also improve impact resistance and freeze-thaw damage.

On the other hand you can also add polypropylene and Nylon fibers, as they do a similar function. I'll add more on this if you need.

Comment: How likely is it that the steel will rust, or are they made out of some sort of corrosion-resistant material, like 316?  Also, do know where I can pick this up ASAP, or are there no large chains that sell it?

Comment: @Michael They are made for this and do not rust. In terms of getting some, I knew a contractor that sold me a container of them :(